# Organize functions - where do you test parameters of function?

Tags: conceptual

i wonder what that would be the best solution on the area to test parameters of function.
"SRP = one function, one responsibility"

few solutions :

- at the beginning of the function
- in a other function

```js
// example "at the beginning of the function"
function main() {
     let arr_errors = [];
     // many tests
     //at the end of tests, if we are errors, we return an array (how do we distinguish between this errors array and result of function ?)

     if([] !== arr_errors) {
         return arr_errors;
     }

     // many process
     return result;
}
```

```js
// example "in a other function"
function main() {
   if([] !== (arr_errors = testA()) {
       displayErrors(arr_errors);
   }
   else {
       return A2();
   }
}
```

What do you think about ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use asserts at the beginning, its called precondition check

Comment: Hello,
you would use the first case.
However, twill you throw an exception instead an return statement ?
In both case, "arr_errors" would be returned